# Count row entries to adjust different column, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I'm trying to update column entries by counting the frequency of row entries in different columns. Here is a sample of my data. Actual data consistes 10k samples each having length of 220. (220 seconds).

```
d = {'ID':['a12', 'a12','a12','a12','a12', 'a12', 'a12','a12','v55','v55','v55','v55','v55','v55','v55', 'v55'], 
     'Exp_A':[0.012,0.154,0.257,0.665,1.072,1.514,1.871,2.144, 0.467, 0.812,1.59,2.151,2.68,3.013,3.514,4.015], 
     'freq':['00:00:00', '00:00:01', '00:00:02', '00:00:03', '00:00:04',
                '00:00:05', '00:00:06', '00:00:07','00:00:00', '00:00:01', '00:00:02', '00:00:03', '00:00:04',
                '00:00:05', '00:00:06', '00:00:07'],
     'A_Bullseye':[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0, 0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0], 'A_Bull_Total':[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2], 'A_Shot':[0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0, 1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Per each second, only Bullseye or Shot can be registered.

Count1: Number of `df.A_Shot == 1` before the first `df.A_Bullseye == 1` for each `ID` is `3 & 2 for ID=a12 and ID=v55 resp`.

Count2: Number of `df.A_Shot == 1` from the end of count1 to the second `df.A_Bullseye == 1`, `1` for `df[df.ID=='a12']` and `2 for df[df.ID=='v55']`

Where `i` in `count(i)` is `df.groupby(by='ID')[A_Bull_Total].max()`. Here `i` is `2`.

So, if I can compute the average count for each i, then I will be able to adjust the values of df.Exp_A using the average of the above counts.

```
mask_A_Shot= df.A_Shot == 1
mask_A_Bullseye= df.A_Bulleseye == 0
mask = mask_A_Shot  & mask_A_Bulleseye 
df[mask.groupby(df['ID'])].mean()
```

Ideally I would like to have something like for each i (Bullseye), how many Shots are needed and how many seconds it took.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a grouping key of `Bullseye` within each ID using `.cumsum` and then you can find how many shots, and how much time elapsed between the bullseyes.

```
import pandas as pd

df['freq'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.freq, unit='s')
df['Bullseye'] = df.groupby('ID').A_Bullseye.cumsum()+1

# Chop off any shots after the final bullseye
m = df.Bullseye <= df.groupby('ID').A_Bullseye.transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().max())

df[m].groupby(['ID', 'Bullseye']).agg({'A_Shot': 'sum', 
                                       'freq': lambda x: x.max()-x.min()})
```

#### Output:

```
              A_Shot     freq
ID  Bullseye                 
a12 1              3 00:00:03
    2              1 00:00:01
v55 1              2 00:00:01
    2              2 00:00:03
```

---

Edit:

Given your comment, here is how I would proceed. We're going to `.shift` the Bullseye column so instead of incrementing the counter at the Bullseye, we increment the counter the row **after** the bullseye. We'll modify `A_Shot` so bullseyes are also considered to be a shot.

```
df['freq'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.freq, unit='s')
df['Bullseye'] = df.groupby('ID').A_Bullseye.apply(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum().fillna(0)+1)

# Also consider Bullseye's as a shot:
df.loc[df.A_Bullseye == 1, 'A_Shot'] = 1

# Chop off any shots after the final bullseye
m = df.Bullseye <= df.groupby('ID').A_Bullseye.transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().max())

df1 = (df[m].groupby(['ID', 'Bullseye'])
            .agg({'A_Shot': 'sum', 
                  'freq': lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()).total_seconds()}))
```

#### Output: `df1`

```
              A_Shot  freq
ID  Bullseye              
a12 1.0            4   4.0
    2.0            2   1.0
v55 1.0            3   2.0
    2.0            3   3.0
```

And now since `freq` is an integer number of seconds, you can do divisions easily:

```
df1.A_Shot / df1.freq

#ID   Bullseye
#a12  1.0         1.0
#     2.0         2.0
#v55  1.0         1.5
#     2.0         1.0
#dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution! But given the size of the actual data(over 10k unique IDs), is there away, say, to count how many total shots/time needed for each Bullseye? So I will have an average figure for each Bullseye?

Comment: @A.Z I can certainly help with that. The one question I have is when `'A_bullseye'` is 1, is this a separate shot that was registered as a bullseye, or is it just the previous shot being registered as a bullseye in the following second? For instance, does `a12` have 3 shots in 3 seconds (the third being the bullseye) or 3 shots that aren't a bullseye, and then the 4th shot at 00:00:04 is a bullseye?

Comment: The second one,  3 shots that aren't a bullseye, and then the 4th shot at 00:00:04 is a bullseye. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: @A.Z. I modified the answer, so that should be more in line with what you need. The timings might not be exactly what you want. I count 00:00:05 - 00:00:06 as 1 second, for instance, but since that represents 2 whole seconds of actions, you may want to just add `1` to the freq column to get a timing that is more accurate.

Comment: This is great. So from your output, in average it takes 3.5 shots to registering the first Bullseye or 3 shots for the second Bullseye. My problem is(the last one) how to make the same conclusion for large data (over 10k unique IDs). Thank you for your petience.

Comment: @A.Z for that you an use a `.groupby`, grouping by the Bullseye level of the index: `df1.groupby(level=1).agg('mean')`will give you the average freq and shots for each bullseye across all IDs